# drop down links gives no output when clicked when files are uploaded on server

Tags: bootstrap-4

bootstrap drop down links  works well and opens drop down on-click event on localhost. when files are uploaded to server the drop down links are not working. it gives blank output when clicked.
I have checked everything. i have rearranged jquery script and tried but get same error.

Answer (score 1):

Plz, check what errors are displayed in console. try to clear all errors one by one and you will have the answer. also plz share your console screenshot if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. i found the error in console and it was because my site is https and links to ajax and jquery  are http and hence it was throwing errors.